# Nutrition deficiency Lines in Nails

Tags: veganism, nutritional-deficiency

My nails start to create a texture like lines on a vegan diet.

Is there a deficiency creating this problem? Is so, what might it be?

Comment: Can you describe the texture in more detail? How do you know it is caused by a nutritional deficiency, or that your self-treatment is effective?

Answer (score 4):

From a quick web search:

> Ridges. Our nails naturally develop slight vertical ridges as we age. However, severe and raised ridges can be a sign of iron deficiency anemia. Nutritional deficiencies, such as a lack of vitamin A, vitamin B, vitamin B12 or keratin can result in fingernail ridges. Hormonal changes can also cause ridges to appear.

> Beau's lines. These appear as horizontal grooves or indents in the nail, and can show up on one or more fingers. These lines can occur following an injury to the nail, such as being hit by a hammer, or an illness that is accompanied by a high fever. Diabetes, malnutrition or zinc deficiency can also cause Beau's lines to develope.

If true, the next step would be to search plant foods with the highest levels of zinc and start to incorporate them in your diet: firm tofu (36% DV), lentils (23% DV), oatmeal (21% DV), 1.5 cup brown rice (19% RDA), hemp hearts, etc, etc. I usually eat about a cup of nuts per day (1/4 cup peanuts, 1/4 cup almonds, 1/4 cup walnuts, 1/4 cup pecans) which gets 38% RDA of zinc.